# RPAD and CASE statment - Oracle SQL - Missing Right Parenthesis Error

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Trying to incorporate a CASE statement in the select statement. One works, but this one returns the error "missing right parenthesis."

> || CASE WHEN RPAD (RA.TAX_ID,9) IS NOT NULL THEN (RA.TAX_ID,9) ELSE  '999999999',9) END

Here's an edited version of the query to give context. The second case statement works.

```
    >SELECT DISTINCT
    > RPAD ('D', 1)
    > || CASE WHEN RPAD (RA.TAX_ID,9) IS NOT NULL THEN (RA.TAX_ID,9) ELSE  '999999999',9) END

    > || CASE WHEN RPAD (RA.ACCOUNT_ENTITY_IND, 1) = 'P' THEN 'I' ELSE ' ' END
    > || RPAD (RA.LAST_NAME, 20)
    > || RPAD (RA.FIRST_NAME, 20)
    > || RPAD (' ', 10)
    > AS HEADER_ROW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `then` and `else` elements are malformed.

```
 || CASE WHEN RPAD (RA.TAX_ID,9) IS NOT NULL THEN (RA.TAX_ID,9) ELSE  '999999999',9) END
                                                  ^         ^^^                  ^^^
```

Presumably the `then` is supposed to be another `rpad()` call, but the `else` looks like it should be a simple literal:

```
 || CASE WHEN RPAD (RA.TAX_ID,9) IS NOT NULL THEN RPAD (RA.TAX_ID,9) ELSE  '999999999' END
```

If you use an IDE like SQL Developer it will highlight simple syntax mistakes like this for you.

Comment: shouldn't it be `CASE WHEN RA.TAX_ID IS NOT NULL`  instead?

Comment: Yes, that would be simpler. `rpad(null, 9)` is still null, but just testing directly for null would be more intuitive...

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be simpler with `coalesce()`?

```
|| COALESCE(RPAD(RA.TAX_ID,9), '999999999') ||
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you not see the unclosed parenthesis here:
      ==>'999999999',9)